# Geometric proof for irrationality of $\pi$

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-geometry, irrational-numbers

Is there a geometric proof for irrationality of $\pi$? That would be neat.

Comment: The asnwer probably is no (or at least other methods must be used as well), compare with [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103786/direct-proof-that-pi-is-not-constructible).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I am not so sure of that. The continued fraction of $\pi$ does not have a nice structure, but there are plenty of generalized continued fraction related with $\pi$ that have a nice structure, and maybe they can "rendered" with a geometric construction.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201076/is-there-any-sans-calculus-proof-of-irrationality-of-pi?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

There is the beautiful short proof by Ivan Niven, [A simple proof that $\pi$ is irrational](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510788), by elementary calculus. I am not aware of a pure geometric proof, but this does not mean, of course, that there might not be one. But it seems that the methods needed to prove the irrationality of $\pi$ always require also calculus, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201076/is-there-any-sans-calculus-proof-of-irrationality-of-pi?lq=1).