# Proof of $\pi$ not being a quadratic irrational number.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, irrational-numbers, pi, transcendental-numbers

Does someone know a proof (books, articles) that $\pi$ is not a quadratic irrational?

The proof should not use that $\pi$ is transcendental.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Niven's proof, which is widely available, shows that $\pi^2$ is irrational (which isn't quite what you want, but it's a start).

Comment: Shameless self-reference : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713467/proving-that-e-is-irrational/879692#879692. As a simple continued fraction is periodic if and only if it is a CF of some irrational quadratic, this proof essentially proved that $\pi$ is not a quadratic irrational.

Comment: @Balarksa Sen ,Sorry, but all I see in your link is a proof that  the CF for $\tanh (1)$ is not periodic. which only implies that $\tanh (1)$ and $e$ are not quadratic over $Q$. Did I miss something?

Comment: Lambert proved $\pi ^2$ is irrational , by use of $\tan (x) = \frac{x}{1-\frac {x^2}{3-\frac{x^2}{5-\frac{x^2}{...}}}}$

Comment: Would the proof that $\pi$ is trancendental be sufficient? It doesn't *use* the fact, it proves it

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103786/direct-proof-that-pi-is-not-constructible

Comment: This is exactly the same question (also marked as duplicate) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008993/is-there-a-direct-proof-that-pi-is-not-the-root-of-an-algebraic-equation-whose-d?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments Lambert proved that $\pi$ is irrational (http://www.pi314.net/eng/lambert.php). Lambert showed that it's irrational by first demonstrating that the continued fraction expansion holds:
$$\tan(x) = \cfrac{x}{1 - \cfrac{x^2}{3 - \cfrac{x^2}{5 - \cfrac{x^2}{7 - {}\ddots}}}}.$$ He then proved that if $x$ is non-zero and a rational number then the expression must be irrational. Consequently because $\tan(\frac {\pi}{4}) = 1$, it follows that $\frac {\pi}{4}$ is irrational and as a result that $\pi$ is irrational. (Refer to the Wikipedia article on the proof of $\pi$ being irrational by Lambert - [Lambert's Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Lambert.27s_proof))

Laczkovich's Proof is a simplification of Lambert's proof (refer [here for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Laczkovich.27s_proof)).

I found a few resources detailing numerous proofs of $\pi$ being irrational, none of them utilising $\pi$ as transcendental. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational) lists 6 different proofs (including Lambert's and Laczkovich's). There was also a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781652/understanding-proof-that-pi-is-irrational) asked on this math forum about understanding the following proof of $\pi$ being irrational making use of polynomials and calculus ([A simple proof that $\pi$ is irrational](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788)).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... OP wants to know if there's a simple proof that $\pi$ isn't a quadratic irrational, i.e., an irrational root of a quadratic with rational coefficients.