# Another proof of e is irrational?

Tags: calculus, analysis, number-theory, exponential-function, irrational-numbers

I find some proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713467/e-is-irrational), but can I prove it in the following way?

Assume $e$ is rational, then $e=\frac{p}q$, both $p$ and $q$ are positive integers. By Lagrange's Remainder Theorem,

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{3!}x^3+...+\frac{1}{q!}x^q+\frac{e^c}{(q+1)!}x^{q+1}, ~~~~~\text{where} ~~~|c|<|x|$$

Let $x=1$ and multiply both sides with $q!$

$$e\cdot q!=q!+q!+q!\frac{1}{2!}+q!\frac{1}{3!}+...+1+\frac{e^c}{q+1}, ~~~~~\text{where} ~~~|c|<1$$

So we have

$$\text{some integer}=\text{some integer} + \frac{e^c}{q+1}$$

Since $0<e^c<3$ and $q+1>3$, (easy to exclude $q\neq 1, q\neq 2$)

So the tail $0<\frac{e^c}{q+1}<1$, and we get a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, it works. It's more of the same, I guess.

Comment: okay, thank you!

Comment: Yes, this works. Not that much different from the usual proof.