# Understanding proof that $\pi$ is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

Reading this: [Simple proof that $\pi$ is irrational](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788), I fail to understand the following part:

> Since $n!f(x)$ has integral coefficients and terms in $x$ of degree
>   not less than $n$, $f(x)$ and its derivatives (...) have integral
>   values for $x=0$; also for $x=\pi=\frac{a}{b}$, since
>   $f(x)=f(\frac{a}{b}-x)$

Assuming this, the rest I understand. But why is this true?

Comment: You might also want to look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational), which explains proofs by Lambert, Hermite, Cartwright, Niven, and Laczkovich.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivatives $f^{(i)}(x)$ have constant term $0$ for $i<n$ since each term of $f(x)$ has degree at least $n$, and thus $f^{(i)}(0)=0$. For $i\ge n$, each term will have a multiplier of $i!$ in front of it, and $n!\mid i!$, so the constant term is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$n!f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.

The derivative of a polynomial with integer coefficients is a polynomial with integer coefficents.

A polynomial with integer coefficients takes on integer values when evaluated at an integer.