# Is there an elementary proof that $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational?

Tags: alternative-proof, irrational-numbers, rationality-testing, algebraic-numbers

Is there an elementary proof that $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational?

The [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) states that if $a$ and $b$ are complex algebraic numbers such that $a \not\in \{0, 1\}$ and $b$ is irrational
then $a^b$ is transcendental.

This answered the question of the nature of $2^{\sqrt{2}}$.

So this got me wondering:
Is there an more elementary proof (i.e., not using the G-S theorem) of the seemingly easier question of whether $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is merely irrational , without going to the transcendental level.

I have played around with this and gotten absolutely nowhere.

That's my question.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you walked through the proof of the GS theorem for this particular special number?

Comment: Many years ago, I looked at a proof in (IIRC) LeVeque volume 2) and understood almost nothing. So, no. Feel free to try. As a great philosopher almost said, "A person's got to know their limitations."

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:complex-numbers]?

Comment: No, there is no easier way. The Gelfond-Schneider theorem (I avoid abbreviations like GS whenever possible) is a very deep result.

Comment: The number $2^{\sqrt2}$ is called the Gelfond-Schneider constant. Perhaps this will help when searching through the literature.

Comment: I did some searching, and Mark Sapir apparently has a half page proof of exactly what you want [here](https://marksapir.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/short-proof-that-2sqrt2-is-not-rational/). This was taken from the MathOverflow [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138247/prove-that-sqrt2-sqrt2-is-an-irrational-number-without-using-a-theorem) that discusses both $2^{\sqrt2}$ and ${\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: Of similar context, although almost certainly not helpful for this particular question: [Direct proof that $\pi$ is not constructible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103786/13130)